# How to create a PowerPoint with Excel VBA without seeing the application

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I want to know how I can create a new PPT from Excel VBA (I already have the code) but without seeing the app while it is creating. I have found some insights but it only works when it opens an existing PPT file, but I am creating a new file.

```
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim excelTable As Excel.Range
Dim SlideTitle As String
Dim SlideText As String
Dim SlideObject As Object
Dim pptTextbox As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim SlideNumber As String

On Error Resume Next
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
Err.Clear

Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add
pptPres.PageSetup.SlideSize = ppSlideSizeOnScreen
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is a particularly bad idea here IMO. If you can't create the PowerPoint app instance, your code should bail out, not keep running as if nothing happened.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify exactly what that code snippet is? Is it your attempt at making an invisible `pptApp`? Or an excerpt from the code that opens an existing ppt file? Because that code doesn't open anything at all, and seems to specify `.Visible = False`, so it's not clear how it connects with the actual question.

Comment: Also... you seem to have the PowerPoint library referenced (`As PowerPoint.Application` *does* compile, right?) - so why then are you late-binding the creation of the application instance? Just do `Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application`.

Comment: To clarify, `Err.Clear` is ***not*** the same thing as `On Error GoTo 0`.  The first just wipes the logged error - the second one actually re-enables error trapping.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my code. I need to have the On error Resume Next because i paste some pictures on the slides and it gives me an error without that code, but wth it it pastes perfectly. Now, with the edited code, the presentation is still visible!

Comment: Also, i made the question really fast (sorry about that) and forgot to erase the .Visible = False, because it doesnt do anything. It even gives me an error saying i cant force the app to not be visible with that code. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Calling `.Active` on a `PowerPoint.Application` does just that - it activates it, which makes the window visible:

```
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Set ppt = New PowerPoint.Application
Debug.Print ppt.Visible  '<--Prints 0 (msoFalse)
ppt.Activate             '<--THIS SHOWS THE WINDOW.
Debug.Print ppt.Visible  '<--Prints -1 (msoTrue)
```

Just remove the `pptApp.Activate` line completely.

As mentioned in the comments, you also need to fix your error handler.  In this case, the best fix is by removing it completely.  `GetObject` returns an existing instance if it exists.  I'm assuming that when you say "create a new PPT" that you ***don't*** mean "attach to a running PowerPoint instance if it exists, otherwise create a new one".  That is what your code currently does.

Also as mentioned in the comments, if you have a reference to Microsoft PowerPoint X.X Object Library (as evidenced by `Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application`), you shouldn't be using `CreateObject` either.  That's for late-binding.  If you have a reference, use early-binding.

Finally, when you create a PowerPoint.Application, it's ***not visible by default***. You can "fix" your code by reducing it to this one line:

```
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok, i edited my code according to your post and the other comments. But it is still visible, maybe because of my pptpresestation.add code?

Comment: Presentations.Add takes an optional parameter, WithWindow.  Set pptPres = Presentations.Add(msoFalse) will give you a reference to a windowless (invisible) presentation that you can do most, if not all, things with.

Comment: I'm using .Add to open an empty presentation file, then inserting files from an external file. When visible, this works fine however PPT crashes when I try to use invisible presentations...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CreateDobriChintulovPresentation()
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPresentation As Object
    Dim pptSlide As Object
    
    ' Create a new PowerPoint application
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    
    ' Add a new presentation
    Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Add
    
    ' Add 5 slides
    For i = 1 To 5
        Set pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(i, ppLayoutText)
        pptSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Slide " & i
    Next i
    
    ' Save the presentation (change the file path as needed)
    pptPresentation.SaveAs "C:\Path\to\YourPresentation.pptx"
    
    ' Clean up
    pptPresentation.Close
    pptApp.Quit
    Set pptSlide = Nothing
    Set pptPresentation = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Presentation created successfully!", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```vb
Sub CreateGreenProcurementPresentation()
    Dim pptApp As Object
    Dim pptPresentation As Object
    Dim slideIndex As Integer
    
    ' Create a PowerPoint application and a new presentation
    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    pptApp.Visible = True ' Set to False if you don't want the application visible
    
    Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Add
    
    ' Add slides
    For slideIndex = 1 To 25
        Dim slide As Object
        Set slide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(slideIndex, ppLayoutTitle)
        
        ' Set title for each slide
        slide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Green Procurement - Slide " & slideIndex
        
        ' Add content or additional text as needed
        ' Example: Adding a bullet point
        slide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "This is an example bullet point."
        
        ' You can add more content or formatting here
        
        ' Wait for a moment to see the slide creation process
        ' Remove this line or change the time if unnecessary
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
    Next slideIndex
    
    ' Clean up
    Set pptPresentation = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**